# Importing into Mongo via "Add Data" oddies

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have a 16k csv file of data and was going to import this to Mongo using the Add Data feature in Compass.  I ensured I had a column with dates set to be a "Date" type.

When I inserted, I got thousands of errors saying the value was not a date.  So I dug through the logs and found an example where one value worked and one value failed.

The data is fairly huge, but I've managed to work down to a reasonable example.

If I try to insert

```
DATE,BOROUGH
21-08-2012
09-09-2012
```

Then Mongo complains that 21-08-2012 is not a valid date.  If I change the order to be 08-21-2012 then both entries are accepted.  Is there anyway to force the import to use the first format?

But secondly, when I do import, the actual dates are wrong:

For example, when I insert the 09-06-2012 date, the document then shows:

```
DATE
2012-09-08T23:00:00.000+00:00
```

ie a day earlier.
Does anyone know why this would be the case? (It happens for the other record as well)